# Where is apc.ini stored

Tags: php, mamp, apc

where is apc.ini stored when using MAMP Pro?

I tried to `locate apc.ini` through the terminal without success.

I would like to increase the overall cache-size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MAMP documentation](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/advanced-functions/edit-configuration-files):

> The configuration files are generated from the settings made within
>   MAMP PRO. MAMP PRO uses templates for this purpose where further
>   configuration options are included. You can edit these templates from
>   the menu item File > Edit template. Here, you have access to options
>   which are not accessible from the MAMP PRO user interface.

It  likely stores all configuration options for PHP modules in the php.ini file generated from the configuration panel.